# SEO: Using structured data to display a category when searching google

Tags: html, seo, breadcrumbs, microdata

I'm trying to use structured data to ensure that a website contains a category in googles search results. You can see what I mean in this example:

http://tinyurl.com/95lryvn

In the example it shows 'Ergonomic Chairs' as the category.

I've been trying to replicate this by using the following:

**Breadcrumbs**

```
<div itemprop="breadcrumb">
  <a href="/">Home</a> &gt;
  <a href="/sets/AlaraReborn/index.html" itemprop="isPartOf">Alara Reborn</a> &gt;
  <a href="ArdentPlea.html">Ardent Plea</a>
</div>
```

The schema.org [isPartOf](http://schema.org/WebPage) itemProp (also visible in the above code sample), but I still am unable to get the category to appear.

Would anyone possibly be able to post a short sample that will display a category when tested via [googles structured data tester](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use **RDFa**, after all, the example you gave " **overstock.com** ", they are using RDFa Here is the excerpt from that page...

```
<ul itemprop="breadcrumb" class="horizontal-list bcrumbs">
  <li typeof="v:Breadcrumb" class="bcrumb-1">
    <a property="v:title" rel="v:url" title="Online Shopping" href="http://www.overstock.com/">Online Shopping</a>
  </li>
  <li typeof="v:Breadcrumb" class="bcrumb-2">
    <span class="bcrumb-arrow"></span>
    <a property="v:title" rel="v:url" title="Office Supplies" href="http://www.overstock.com/Office-Supplies/22/store.html">
    Office Supplies</a>
  </li>

    <li typeof="v:Breadcrumb" class="bcrumb-3">
    <span class="bcrumb-arrow"></span>
    <a property="v:title" rel="v:url" title="Office Furniture" href="http://www.overstock.com/Office-Supplies/Office-Furniture/310/dept.html">
      Office Furniture</a>
    </li>


    <li typeof="v:Breadcrumb" class="bcrumb-4">
     <span class="bcrumb-arrow"></span>
      <a property="v:title" rel="v:url" title="Office Chairs &amp; Accessories" href="http://www.overstock.com/Office-Supplies/Office-Chairs-Accessories/3637/cat.html">
      Office Chairs &amp; Accessories</a>
    </li>


    <li typeof="v:Breadcrumb" class="bcrumb-5">
      <span class="bcrumb-arrow"></span>
      <a property="v:title" rel="v:url" title="Ergonomic Chairs" href="http://www.overstock.com/Office-Supplies/Ergonomic-Chairs/22529/subcat.html">
      Ergonomic Chairs</a>
      <i class="last-child"></i>
    </li>
```

`

And I can explain everything here but I strongly believe that I can't match up the explanation given by Google.

So, in case you have not gone through these explanations(links below) I strongly recommend you to go through them. I hope these will solve your problem.

- [Rich Snippets](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170)
- [RDFa](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146898)